# Where did Prisma took my name from when generating the migration README?

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I'm starting to work with this amazing toolkit and noticed that when I generate migration files Prisma also creates a README file alongside the new schema. This file happens to have my personal name in the subtitle: `This migration has been generated by Teodoro at 10/17/2020, 9:52:22 PM. You can check out the state of the schema after the migration.`.

What intrigues me is the following:

- My name is Teodoro, (but that's ok).
- I didn't have to set my name when started working with the toolkit in any place.
- My computer's name is completely different from my name.
- My username in the computer is completely different from my name.
- This project has been created from scratch for testing purposes and I didn't include any git repositories from where it could take my name from.
- `grep -iRn "teodoro"` on project's root only returned my name included in the misterious readme files.

I can't imagine any other place from which Prisma took my name to generate this README file, so where did it came from??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was so intrigued that I cloned Prisma's repo and searched on the readme creation files for this.

The migration module uses `git-user-name` package so it got my name from my global git configuration.